# Rav4 2015 Limited Edition high fuel consumption

Tags: toyota, fuel-consumption, rav4

I bought a Toyota Rav4 AWD 2015 Limited edition since 1 month and it's consuming a lot of fuel: about 17L/100Km in the city which is a high number for 4 cylinder SUV no?

What could be the issue?

Comment: How many miles are on it? What's the typical fuel consumption for other RAV4's of that year/engine? What maintenance has been done on it before/since you got it? Is there any black suet on the inside of the tailpipe? Is it a 4WD? AWD? If so, do you run it in 4WD? What is the tire pressure? What have you tried to do to remedy the situation thus far?

Comment: What is the route you take to work? Highway with a 50mph cruise or rough tracks at 5mph?

Comment: Are you stuck in traffic a lot of the time? Does that model have start/stop technology? Published urban consumption figure is approx 13 L/100km.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes I was stuck in traffic about 30% of my trips, yes it has start/stop technology, does it has an impact on fuel consumption?

Comment: @SolarMike I didn't go a lot to highways, most of my trips had some traffic but although I saw 17L/100Km is too much even in traffics, no ?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 it has 100K miles, on internet I saw that this Rav4 Limited Edition 2015 should have about 10L/100Km in cities...
It is a AWD,

For the maintenance I can send you the carfax report where it contains all the maintenance stuffs done in Canada, how can I send you those ?
I still didn't do anything, I noticed this behavior since 1 week

Comment: I can improve my fuel consumption by a factor of two if I cruise the highways compared to up and down the mountain. Then add driving style or skills…

Comment: @Jad remember that the manufacturer's published data aren't what you will actually get, but a useful way of comparing vehicles from different manufacturers, tested under similar ideal conditions, and are almost always "optimistic". The actual consumption is influenced by a wide range of factors.

Comment: @JadChahine - The reason I asked about maintenance is the O2 sensors play a key role in  fuel consumption. If it has 100k miles on it, it's due for O2 sensors. If they've not been changed, I'd highly recommend. Spark plugs, air filter, and oil change may help as well. Cleaning the MAF. Lots of stuff. Also, make sure on what you're seeing as "normal" fuel mileage (10L/100km) is for an AWD vehicle. AWD doesn't help fuel mileage at all.